# Function stub not working with sinon and mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to stub functions for my test suite and it is currently not working as expected. I am new to using mocha and sinon and am looking for direction in how to make this work:

Here is a snippet of the code that is being tested which is found in functions/purchaseOrder.js. The AccountStatus, creditStatus and productStatus are local functions within the file:

```
var orderHandling=function(clientAccount ,product,inventory,inventoryThreshold,creditCheckMode){

var aStautus=AccountStatus(clientAccount);

var cStatus=creditStatus(clientAccount, creditCheckMode);

var pStatus=productStatus(product,inventory,inventoryThreshold);
...more
}
```

and this is how I am trying to test it:

```
import testFunctions = require('./functions/purchaseOrder.js');
beforeEach(function() {
  stub=sinon.stub(testFunctions, "AccountStatus");
  stub1=sinon.stub(testFunctions, "productStatus");
  stub2=sinon.stub(testFunctions, "creditStatus");  // stub 'calPoints' function
})
it('Initial Test', function() {
  var clientAccount = {
    age: 2,
    balance: 500,
    creditScore: 50
  }
  stub.onCall(0).returns("very good");
  stub1.onCall(0).returns("available");
  stub2.onCall(0).returns("good");

  var creditCheckMode = 'restricted';

  var product = "productname"

  var inventory = [{
    name: "hello",
    productQuantity: 578
  }]

  var inventoryThreshold = 500

  assert.equal(testFunctions.orderHandling(clientAccount, product, inventory, inventoryThreshold, creditCheckMode), "accepted");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my question through some digging myself. It turns out that I am trying to stub out the variable that is assigned to the **anonymous** function it is referencing. Sinon is unable to find this anonymous function and therefore is not stubbing out the method. To fix this I had to change the code to be: `var productStatus = {prodStatus: function() {...}`
and then stub out the functions like so:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(testFunctions.productStatus, "prodStatus"); 
stub.onCall(0).returns("available");
```

This works perfectly. Hope this helps someone!